# Can't redirect url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem making 301 redirects via `.htaccess`. The website is based on WordPress and I need to redirect this link:

`www.domainname.pl/?lang=pl&sec0=nasz_zespol&sec1=Mateusz`

to:

`www.domainname.pl/o-nas/nasi-trenerzy/mateusz-szablowski/`

but using:

```
RewriteRule ^?lang=pl&sec0=nasz_zespol&sec1=Mateusz/$ hwww.domainname.pl/o-nas/nasi-trenerzy/mateusz-szablowski/  [R=301,L]
```

it's not working - this redirects me to homepage.

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule /?lang=pl&sec0=nasz_zespol&sec1=Mateusz www.domainname.pl/o-nas/nasi-trenerzy/mateusz-szablowski/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Panther's version should work for this one specific case. I you need a more flexible version, you should update your question. ANd where you went wrong: you started the URI with `?` which should be `/` and tried to redirect to `hwww.` instead of `www.` otherwise your rule is the same as Panther's ;)